# React navigation ios modal: make possible to drag the modal higher than from its start

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I use react-navigation > 5 and try to configure a iOS type modal. The one they show in [the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#transitionpresets) works
well but I would like the modal to appear and stop in a certain height (like one third of the screen) and let the possibility to the user to drag it higher(with a certain margin from the top) or disabled the modal by swiping it down.
I checked all the config used in `ModalPresentationIOS` but I still have difficulties to get the right behavior. For the moment I'm only able to set up the correct height, but the user can't drag the modal higher. Here my config:

```js
    <RootStack.Navigator
      headerMode="none"
      mode="modal"
      screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
        cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'transparent' },
        cardOverlayEnabled: true,
        gestureEnabled: true,
        headerStatusBarHeight:
          navigation.dangerouslyGetState().routes.indexOf(route) > 0
            ? 0
            : undefined,
          gestureDirection: 'vertical',
        transitionSpec: {
          open: TransitionIOSSpec,
          close: TransitionIOSSpec,
        },
        cardStyleInterpolator: forModalPresentationIOS,
        headerStyleInterpolator: forFade
      })}
    >
```

With this config for `forModalPresentationIOS`:

```js
function forModalPresentationIOS({
  index,
  current,
  next,
  inverted,
  layouts: { screen },
  insets,
}: StackCardInterpolationProps): StackCardInterpolatedStyle {
  const isLandscape = screen.width > screen.height;
  const topOffset = isLandscape ? 0 : 10;
  const statusBarHeight = insets.top;
  const aspectRatio = screen.height / screen.width;
  const topMargin = 100; // Variable that I use to set up the height of the modal

  const progress = add(
    current.progress.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: [0, 1],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    }),
    next
      ? next.progress.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 1],
          outputRange: [0, 1],
          extrapolate: 'clamp',
        })
      : 0
  );

  const translateY = multiply(
    progress.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
      outputRange: [
        screen.height,
        index === 0 ? 0 : topMargin,
        (index === 0 ? statusBarHeight : 0) - topOffset * aspectRatio,
      ],
    }),
    inverted
  );

  const overlayOpacity = progress.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1, 1.0001, 2],
    outputRange: [0, 0.3, 1, 1],
  });

  const scale = isLandscape
    ? 1
    : progress.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1, 2],
        outputRange: [
          1,
          1,
          screen.width ? 1 - (topOffset * 2) / screen.width : 1,
        ],
      });

  const borderRadius = isLandscape
    ? 0
    : index === 0
    ? progress.interpolate({
        inputRange: [0, 1, 1.0001, 2],
        outputRange: [0, 0, isIphoneX() ? 38 : 0, 10],
      })
    : 10;

  return {
    cardStyle: {
      overflow: 'hidden',
      borderTopLeftRadius: borderRadius,
      borderTopRightRadius: borderRadius,
      marginTop: index === 0 ? 0 : statusBarHeight,
      marginBottom: index === 0 ? 0 : topOffset,
      transform: [{ translateY }, { scale }],
    },
    overlayStyle: { opacity: overlayOpacity },
  };
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Haven't found any right config, so I came with this solution that works. We just check when the user press the header of the modal and move it, and adjust the marginTop of the modal to make it move. Here the code:

*RootStack*

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
} from '@react-navigation/stack';

// import components
import MainNav from './MainNav';
import ModalScreen from '../screens/Modal/ModalScreen';

// Types
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Main: undefined;
  ModalScreen: { handleModalHeight: (arg1: number) => void };
};
interface Props {};
// ***

const { height } = Dimensions.get('window');
const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

const RootNav: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = props => {

  function handleModalHeight(modalHeight: number): void {
    if(modalHeight >= Math.floor(height/3) && modalHeight <= Math.floor(height -(height/3))){
      setMarginTop(modalHeight);
    }
  }

  const [ marginTop, setMarginTop ] = useState<number>(Math.floor(height -(height/3)));

  return(
    <RootStack.Navigator
      mode="modal"
      headerMode="none"
    >
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="Main"
        component={MainNav}
      />
      <RootStack.Screen
        name="ModalScreen"
        component={ModalScreen}
        initialParams={{handleModalHeight}}
        options={{
          cardStyle: {
            overflow: 'hidden',
            borderTopLeftRadius: 38,
            borderTopRightRadius: 38,
            marginTop
          },
          gestureResponseDistance: {
            vertical: marginTop
          }
        }}
      />
    </RootStack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default RootNav;
```

*ModalScreen*

```js
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  PanResponder,
  YellowBox,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  PanResponderInstance
} from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';

YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  'Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state',
]);

import { RootStackParamList } from '../../navigation/RootNav';

type ModalScreenRouteProps = RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'ModalScreen'>;
type Props = {
  route: ModalScreenRouteProps;
};

const ModalScreen: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({route}) => {

  const handleModalHeight = route.params?.handleModalHeight;
  const [ isModalSpreading, setIsModalSpreading ] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const panResponder = useRef<PanResponderInstance | null>(null);

  useEffect(()=> {
    panResponder.current = PanResponder.create({
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
        const { moveY } = gestureState;
        if(isModalSpreading) {
          handleModalHeight(moveY);
        }
      },
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        setIsModalSpreading(false)
      }
    })
  }, [isModalSpreading]);

  return (
    <Container {...panResponder.current?.panHandlers} >
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPressIn={() => setIsModalSpreading(true)}
        onPressOut={() => setIsModalSpreading(false)}
      >
        <Header>
          <BarHeader/>
        </Header>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      <BodyModal>
        <Text>ModalPlace</Text>
      </BodyModal>
    </Container>
  );
}

const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
`;
const Header = styled.View`
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
`;
const BarHeader = styled.View`
  width: 60px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 2.5px;
`;
const BodyModal = styled.View`
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
`;

export default ModalScreen;
```

This method is rough and with poor performance. The best I think is too open a classic modal with transparent background and to use an Animated.View to animate the height of a View when the user will drag the modal up.